# Why is the Curve Modifier flipping my meshes normals

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, normals, curve-modifier

I'm using an array modifier and a curve modifier to curve a mesh object around a curve path.  Unfortunately, the normals are being flipped somehow, and I don't know why.  The path curve and mesh object are on the origin.  The scale is at 1 for the mesh object and path curve.  What is causing my normals to flip on my mesh objects?  Any help is appreciated.[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: Select mesh and <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and move to find you sweet spot.

I try to reproduce you issue and found that when I grab(<kbd>G</kbd>) mesh and move along Z axis(<kbd>Z</kbd>) when mesh was move close together it start deform.

[image]

Comment: Hey Terg Turry, thanks for the suggestions.  I am new to Blender and I think what you are saying is to move the curve and array around to different axis points.  This is what I tried with no change at all, so that is why I am wondering if I did it correctly.  I moved the curve and object around the grid separately and as a unit.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I just edit my answer by reproduce your problem. If that can't solve your problem please consider to share you blend file so we can look up your setup.

Comment: Thank You!!!  It worked.  I have spent at least 3 hours trying to solve this problem.  Thanks for spending your time to solve it.